# How to remove Blender in the command line ?

Tags: command-line

I tried to remove Blender in the command line , in order to install it anew because of flawed selection in edit mode. So, this is what I typed and the error message I got, I do not understand the error-message.

```
 sudo apt-get remove blender
```

[sudo] password for terazer: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: What is your operating system(distribution)? Did you try restarting PC and trying again?

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 17.1 rebecca, I ve tried the same command after restarting.

Comment: Another `apt-get` i.e. `dpkg` instance is running..whats the output of `lsof +D /var/lib/dpkg/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for understanding the message, the lock file is used to stop more than one package manager trying to modify the system at once. If this weren't here the system could easily become damaged beyond repair.

Therefore this normally means that another package manager is running at the same time. Do you have a graphical front-end open, like the Ubuntu Software Center or synaptic? As a general rule, you can't have the graphical apps open and use the terminal to install software at the same time. Try seeing if there is a dpkg utility running by running `pgrep dpkg` - if you see a list of process IDs that *probably* means dpkg is currently modifying the packages on the system.